# What is the best way to dynamically set images dependant on resolution(reduce bandwidth and load times)

Tags: javascript, html, image, dynamic

I was  wondering, how I should set and image to be the entire width of a persons browser without using the old method of loading a giant picture at 100%.

Is it a good idea to check the width using javascript and change the image src.

```
if(browserWidth<=700) {
    set image src to small.jpg
} else if(browserWidth>=1200 && browserWidth<=1600) {
    set image src to medium.jpg
} else {
    set image src to large.jpg
}
```

Will this reduce unneccessary bandwidth usage? Will it fix weird streches?

I just find it weird to try and stuff a 1200px image and set it as 100% for all different devices, such as netbooks and cellphones.

Is there more effective ways of loading main page images? If so what is it?
(Also, those image size shrinkers help with this).

How does bing make their videos/images load so quickly? Do they use a similar method?

Comment: hmm, you might be right, except... I think they can only change background-image: They are unable to change an img src tag

Comment: you can check in chrome devtool ctrl+alt+i resources should show you if it works. And it should work. I think you can leave the src empty on load... But not sure if that is okay for SEO... Else load the smallest picture first, and replace if screen is bigger... but why load 2 images lol